# Is there a comprehensive reference list of all Solidity commands?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is there a comprehensive reference list of all Solidity commands?

Answer (score 4):

The [Solidity In Depth](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/solidity-in-depth.html) section of the the [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is comprehensive.

There's also a reference-style [cheat sheet](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#cheatsheet), though it's a bit more limited in terms of content.

Answer (score 0):

This cheat-sheet might help you get started on this. It also has a best practices and security guidelines which will also help you to write some good quality code.

https://github.com/manojpramesh/solidity-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

YES! We've just shipped it [here](http://reference.auditless.com/cheatsheet).

P.S. It covers Vyper too.